# What word am I looking for? Related to unique parts or non-universal components

Tags: meaning

For example. You cannot use Mac parts in a Windows computer because they are ________ parts.  <- I believe the word I am looking for starts with an S.

Unique, not universal, can only be used on a specific platform etc..

any help would be great thanks!

Comment: incompatible, but it doesn't start with an S

Answer (score 2):

perhaps **[proprietary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proprietary)**?

```
1:  one that possesses, owns, or holds exclusive right to something; specifically :  
    proprietor 1
2:  something that is used, produced, or marketed under exclusive legal right of the 
    inventor or maker; specifically :  a drug (as a patent medicine) that is protected by 
    secrecy, patent, or copyright against free competition as to name, product,
    composition, or process of manufacture
3:  a business secretly owned by and run as a cover for an intelligence organization
```

This word is often used to refer to this sort of situation, where no-one else is allowed to manufacture the part in question as the technology is wholly owned by the **proprietor** (Apple in your example), and because the technology is product-specific it (usually by design) won't work with another product (such as a PC).

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark the answer as correct if you think it has helped.

Answer (score 1):

## incompatible

[Definition](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incompatible):

> 1.3 (Of equipment, computer programs, etc.) not capable of being used in combination:
>
> "all four prototype camcorders used special tapes and were
> incompatible with each other"

Your sentence would therefore be:

> You cannot use Mac parts in a Windows computer because they are
> incompatible parts.

This is not a word starting with "s", but I think it's the most relevant, appropriate and commonly used. I couldn't find any appropriate synonym that met the "s-word" constraint.

[Synonyms include](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/incompatible):

> unsuited, mismatched, ill-matched; ill-assorted; irreconcilable,
> conflicting, opposed, opposite, contradictory, antagonistic,
> antipathetic; clashing, inharmonious, discordant